# Neo4j BFS over nodes with a given label

Tags: java, neo4j, breadth-first-search

On Neo4j, programatically I run BFS as follows:

```
public Traverser runBFSPaths(Node startNode) {
    TraversalDescription myTraversal = graphDb.traversalDescription()
       .breadthFirst()
       .relationships(relationshipType)
       .evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition());
    return myTraversal.traverse(startNode);
}
```

If I have multiple labels of nodes (NodeType), how can I restrict the BFS above, only to one nodeType (without using Cypher)? Or is it much easier to express this in Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the [path expander procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) in APOC Procedures. These use bfs expansion by default, and let you specify node labels for whitelist, blacklist, or for end nodes you're interested in. You can also specify the relationships to use for the expansion.

Comment: Do all APOCs require running via Cypher? -- is there a way to directly use them in the traversal description maybe?

Comment: Not directly from the traversal description itself, as the procedures in question create and use their own traversal description with built-in label and relationship filtering and more. You can always add your own custom evaluator to evaluate labels and return the relevant Evaluation.